# Pad binaries in elixir by a variable amount

Tags: binary, elixir

I need a function that can produce a binary that consists of a certain number of 0 octets. I though the following would be possible

```
def padding(length) do
  bits = length * 8
  <<0::bits>>
end
```

OR

```
def padding(length) do
  <<0::binary-size(length)>>
end
```

Both of these fail with an argument error. Why is it not passible to pass a variable to create a binary in elixir. It looks from this link like it would be possible in erlang. http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2008-December/040703.html

Also what would be a simple way to implement this function in Elixir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost there. Your first attempt needs an explicit `size()` to work:

```
iex(1)> length = 5
5
iex(2)> bits = length * 8
40
iex(3)> <<0::size(bits)>>
<<0, 0, 0, 0, 0>>
```

I don't think there's a way to create this binary using `::binary-size(N)`. The Erlang mailing list thread you linked to also multiplies the number of bytes with 8 before constructing the binary. Elixir just doesn't allow expressions in `size()` like Erlang does though.

You can also use `:binary.copy/2` but I'm not sure if that's as efficient as the above:

```
iex(4)> :binary.copy(<<0>>, 5)
<<0, 0, 0, 0, 0>>
```

Comment: looks good though I am still curious about the history of why elixir doesn't allow expressions when erlang does

Comment: @PeterSaxton the root cause is [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_bitstring.erl#L171-L180). I am unable to come up with a reason of why `size` accepts variables and `unit` explicitly requires in integer term: `len = 8; <<0::size(len)-unit(8)>>` works, while `len = 8; <<0::size(len)-unit(len)>>` fails in line 178 of the code I linked above. Also, `<<0::8*5>>` works while neither `<<0::len*5>>` nor `<<0::8*len>>` does not.

Comment: Yeah I'm also confused why Elixir doesn't support this as that mailing list post is from 2008, which means Erlang has supported this since years before Elixir's first commit.